# ng-show with function not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It is suppoesed to show the h2 when function returns 1 but even though it returns 1 it never show the header.

The following angular code:

```
<md-virtual-repeat layout-wrap class="toast" ng-repeat="member in members| filter:searchText | orderBy:orderByFunction" >
                                    <div class="subtitle"  ng-show="showContrib(member) == 1" >
                                        <h2> CONTRIBUTORS {{member.price}} -- {{member.amount}}</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="subtitle"  ng-show="showTop(member) == 1" >
                                        <h2> TOP CONTRIBUTORS  {{Number(member.price)}} -- {{Number(member.amount)}}</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <md-whiteframe class="md-whiteframe-z3 frieed" style="margin:6px; padding: 19px;" flex-sm="35" flex-gt-sm="25" flex-gt-md="20" layout layout-align="center center">
                                        {{ member.amount}}
                                    </md-whiteframe>
                                </md-virtual-repeat>
```

with this js code:

```
$scope.showTop = function(member){
        if($scope.topShow == 1){

            return 0;
        }
        if(parseInt(member.price) < parseInt(member.amount)){
    console.log('came here price');
             $scope.topShow = 1;
            return 1;

        }
        return 0;

};
    $scope.showContrib = function(member){
         $scope.conShow = 1;
//        console.log('price='+member.price+"amount"+member.amount);
        if($scope.conShow == 1){
            return 0;
        }
        if(parseInt(member.price) == parseInt(member.amount)){
           $scope.conShow = 1;
            return 1;

        }
        return 0;

};
```

it always evaluates to false even though I can see in console.log that topShow and conShow is changing to 1.

Comment: Can you try with === instead of == in ng-show conditions.

Comment: What condition need to check in function? As of now its satisfy the 1st condition and will return the value as 0. After that only its checking the 2nd conditions. So it's printing 1 in console , but first itself it returns 0 to HTML.

Comment: How did  checked that function return 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here.

One, as @LokiSinclair pointed out, is that `$scope.showContrib` will always return 0.

Second, is the use of a function in `ng-show`. When you use a function to determine the value of `ng-show`, this function will re-evaluate over and over again. In your `$scope.showTop` function, you change the value of `$scope.topShow` to 1 and return 1, but since you change the value of a scope object, it can be a matter of milliseconds until this function is called again, only this time it will return 0.

Comment: I just had to basically rethink the whole thing and load data with 2 different ajax functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you set `conShow` to 1, and then `return 0`. See here:

```
$scope.conShow = 1;
if($scope.conShow == 1){
    return 0;
}
```

So it's not actually checking your later logic, to return anything other than 0.

Comment: I didn't actually change any of your code, more highlighted potential logic fail. What did you change?